# How do I define custom filters for minimal use of django templates?

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a python project that I'm using Django templates for to generate C++ source code.

I picked Django because the template language is quite restrictive and has a very large community making it easy for end-use developers to use and get help with.

I'm failing to add custom filters for my project (to translate one set of type names into another) because I have not done the normal django setup.

Instead:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
import django

if not django.conf.settings.configured : django.conf.settings.configure()
django.setup()
```

Lets me use Django templates perfectly but not define custom filters.

My custom filter is called ctypes_filters.py and I reference it in the template as

```
{% load ctypes_filters %}
```

Running my generation script results in the following error:

```
django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'ctypes_filters' is not a valid tag library: Template library ctypes_filters not found, tried 

django.templatetags.ctypes_filters
```

How can I get django to find the filter without setting up a full Django project (database definitions etc)?

I know that other templating solutions are available (and are probably more light-weight) but I'm really keen to use Django's simple and elegant templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of Django template tags is done by convention rather than a configuration setting (see the [code layout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) section of the template tags docs).

Put the `ctypes_filter.py` in a `templatetags` directory in an installed app (I've called it `myapp` here).  Add an empty `__init__.py` to both the `myapp` and `templatetags` directories. The app doesn't need any other files you might commonly find in a Django app, like `models.py` or `views.py`.

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        ctypes_filter.py
```

Then include `myapp` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` when configuring your settings.

```
django.conf.settings.configure(
    INSTALLED_APPS=('myapp',),
)
```

Comment: Looks good. I'm still getting an error, perhaps because it's not looking in the cwd:

        'django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'ctypes_filter' is not a valid tag library: Template library ctypes_filter not found, tried django.templatetags.ctypes_filter,django_apps.templatetags.ctypes_filter'

Comment: I've added django_apps/templatetags/ctypes_filter.py and created an empty __init__.py in both directories. Working now as required. 

Thanks.